# Mapping data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map one data frame to another in python. The 2 tables are:

```
name    age   grade   code
Willard 20     88     2877
 Al     19     92     3000
Omar    22     95     3710
Spencer 21     70     4001
Abin    18     76     2338
```

and :

```
sec.Code  sec.number 
2877       10003
1244       13772    
3000       98822
2338       11223    
4553       22996
```

The "code" column of the first table and the "sec.Code" of the second table refer to the same thing and therefore I want to map the "code" to the "sec.number" and if the code does not exist in the second table, to fill with a relevant message.

In simple words, I want to create a final table exactly like this:

```
name    age  grade  code  sec.number
Willard 20    88    2877  10003
Al      19    92    3000  98822
Omar    22    95    3710  Not match
Spencer 21    70    4001  Not match
Abin    18    76    2338  11223
```

I dont have much experience with python and this is what I tried:

```
for i in First_table['code']:
   for j in Second_table['sec.Code']:
    if i == j:
        First_table['sec_number'] = Second_table['sec.Code']
    else:
        First_table['sec_number'] = "Not match"
```

Obviously this does not work. Could you tell me how to assign values to specific cells through the iterations? And of course if there is a more effective and "smart" way to do  this?

Thanks

Comment: Ok. So what's the question?

Comment: Could you help me with this?

Comment: Sure what are stuck on? What approach of yours didn't work and what error are you getting?

Comment: I mean how to do it in pyhon. Thanks

Comment: You need to at least have attempted it yourself. And if you did, show your approach and where you're stuck etc. Since you're dealing with dataframes, we're assuming you have some experience with them

Comment: I tried to iterate over the 2 tables by comparing the  'code' and the sec.number and if there is a "match" to add the corresponding sec.number to the column. Otherwise to produce a relevant mesage. Is it easier to do it using joins?

Comment: @RGRGRG, Your method seems a bit long-winded. Nevertheless, can you please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50393849/edit) your question to include your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Option 1***
**`merge`** left on **`code`**, right on **`sec.Code`**:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='code', right_on='sec.Code', how='left').drop(['sec.Code'], axis=1).fillna('Not match')

name       age  grade   code    sec.number
0   Willard 20  88      2877         10003
1   Al      19  92      3000         98822
2   Omar    22  95      3710     Not match
3   Spencer 21  70      4001     Not match
4   Abin    18  76      2338         11223
```

***Option 2***
**`set_index`** with **`join`**:

```
df1.set_index('code').join(df2.set_index('sec.Code')).reset_index().fillna('Not match')

    code    name    age grade   sec.number
0   2877    Willard 20  88           10003
1   3000    Al      19  92           98822
2   3710    Omar    22  95       Not match
3   4001    Spencer 21  70       Not match
4   2338    Abin    18  76           11223
```

Comment: Glad to help.  If this answered your question, check out [What to do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)